# How can I view users statistics for Teams over specific time periods?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, statistics

I'd like to see how well Team users are doing over a specific time period

**Example link**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/c/myteam/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month
```

However the interface only allow me to select weekly, monthly, quarterly, all and I'm looking more for a from x date to y date kind of thing.

How can I specify dates?

Comment: Just to clarify you like to filter on a specific start and end date viewing this link `https://stackoverflow.com/c/yourteam/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month`?

Comment: Hi Petter, yes - generally the monthly tab only shows from the start of the month until today, same for the quarter (from the start of the quarter to today) etc.  I'm looking more for a from x date to y date kind of thing.

Comment: Great, I will clarify (edit your question) which page your interested in filtering by dates. As far as I know it's not possibile, but maybe there is some nice back door in filters so I will leave the actual answer to an SE employee.